# Image for <option> works in firefox but not works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

html:

```
<select size="10" style="width: 325px; background-color: #fff;" class="postCode">
    <option value="36621746_0S_F">6 Upperkirkgate Aberdeen</option>
    <option value="31560744_0S_F">12A Upperkirkgate Aberdeen</option>
    <option value="31560745_0S_F">12B Upperkirkgate Aberdeen</option>
    <option value="36621735_0S_F">36 Upperkirkgate Aberdeen</option>
    <option value="35390362_0S_F">48-58 Upperkirkgate Aberdeen</option>
</select>
```

Css:

```
.postCode {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.postCode option
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url('../img/house.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

---

**In Firefox**

[image: In Firefox]

**In Chrome**

[image: In Chrome]

Please help me.

UPD: 
 - IE8 in the same result as in Chrome

Comment: Feel free to comment/CC yourself on http://webkit.org/b/83932

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I do it with lists**

JS:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.postcodeAddressList = function() {

        this.each(function() {
            var el = $(this),
            li = el.find('li'),
            i = li.length;

            strippedList(el);

            while(i--) {
                $(li[i]).on("click", function(e){ 
                    strippedList(el);
                    $(e.currentTarget).attr("selected", "selected");
                    el.attr("data",$(e.currentTarget).attr("data"));
                });
            } 
        });

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

strippedList =  function ( el) {
    var li = el.find('li'),
        i = li.length; 

     while(i--) {
         if($( li[i] ).attr("selected")!= 'defined') {
             $(li[i]).removeAttr("selected");
         }
         if (i%2) {
             $(li[i]).attr("stripped","stripped");
         }else {
             $(li[i]).removeAttr("stripped");
         }
     }

}
```

CSS:

```
.postCode li[stripped="stripped"] {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.postCode li[selected="selected"] {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.postCode li
{
    background-image: url('../img/house.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5% 50%;
    padding: 7px 0 7px 4em;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
}
.postCode[disabled="disabled"] {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.postCode {
    background-color: white;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-left: -10px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 340px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="postCode" data="29392449_0S_F">
    <li data="26850525_898354S_F">Andrew Begg 24-26 Upperkirkgate Aberdeen</li>
    <li data="31763873_0S_F" stripped="stripped">Flat 1 12 Upperkirkgate Aberdeen</li>
    <li data="31763875_0S_F">Flat 1 14 Upperkirkgate Aberdeen</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Use:

```
...
$('.postCode').postcodeAddressList();
...


...
var value = $('.postCode').attr("data");
...
```

### Result:

Mozilla

[image]

Chrome
[image]

IE8
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Some browsers implement drop down menus using native controls and do not allow options to be styled. Short of replacing the element with a collection of other elements and a stack of JavaScript, there is nothing you can do about this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

`-webkit-appearance:none;`

and

`-webkit-box-sizing: contents-box;`

There is more discussion about the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992215/html5-search-input-no-background-image-in-chrome)

Comment: This will remove the down arrow from select