# Override the -webkit-search-cancel-button

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

I'm trying to override the small (x) that appears in the search bar, to have it do more than clear the search

Currently this is my search bar:
HTML:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" id="inputSearch" placeholder="Search for node" onchange="searchForNode(this)"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#inputSearch::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
    position:relative;
    right:20px;    
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to remove that " X " or style differently

Comment: I want to style it differently, also i've noticed that it doesnt appear on firefox; is there another way to have it appear on firefox because the examples that I saw also have that problem.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Egh8K/1/)**

1)  Mozilla treats search inputs as text. For Webkit browsers however (Chrome, Safari), the search input is styled as a client created HTML

2) **for chrome**

**CSS**

**[Article link](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs)**

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {

  /* Remove default */
  -webkit-appearance: none;

  /* Now your own custom styles */
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
  /* Will place small red box on the right of input (positioning carries over) */

}
```

**[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992215/html5-search-input-no-background-image-in-chrome)**

Answer (score 11):

An example for Chrome:

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  margin-left: .4em;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='%23777'><path d='M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z'/></svg>");
  cursor: pointer;
}
```