# Styling the X on a search input box?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML input field, like this `<input id='namebox' type="search" placeholder="Name" class="lensinput"/>` My browser is adding a little X to clear the box (I think this is part of HTML 5, but I am also using zurb foundation). How can I style the x? If I right-click and inspect element in chrome dev tools the x disappears (I think because the field loses focus). If I look thru the HTML tree in dev tools, I don't seen an element for the x.

How do I style the x with CSS? Is that possible?

Comment: one thing i learned -> never try to style user-agent rendered elements like select .. type="search" might be similiar, if you want it, rebuild it

Comment: I think that the x is part of the OS's UI framework's rendering of a search box, and therefore is not stylable through normal CSS. There may be some browser specific options though.

Comment: Slightly different question, but same answer: [Override the -webkit-search-cancel-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928819/override-the-webkit-search-cancel-button)

Answer (score 13):

This is working for me running Chrome 83:

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-image: url(" ### Inline SVG of Choice ### ");
}
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image: Chrome 83]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I used 'content' property instead of 'background-image' to render the svg.

Comment: When I use content, nothing appears.. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

On web-kit based browsers, you can do a trick to set css styles to this specific case.
You can access the user agent generated element through the `::-webkit-search-cancel-button {` selector.

Then, disable the default element, and add a custom 'X' through the `:after` and `content` css3 properties, setting any style you want...

```
::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-search-cancel-button:after {
    content: 'X';
    font-style: italic;
    color: red;
}
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/QYLNw/1/

Comment: Your solution does not seem to work anymore on Chrome 62