# Javascript Datatable

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

I have this small problem I can't solve.
I can't seem to find where the (x) clear search bar button is being made, I mean where in  the CSS or JS file it is located?
I just want to change its color into white but I cannot find something like background-image or background: url('svg file')

[image]

I am using these files:
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: Use your browser dev tools element inspector to see what rules apply to the element(s) and add a more specific rule based on those selectors

Comment: Please put a working snippet in your question which we can try out. I can't debug minified css/js files! But first have a look in your browser - inspect the x element and see exactly who/where the style is being set.

Comment: Note that the `<input>` type attribute is `search`. Therefore, how (or even if) that `x` is generated is browser-specific. See the `search` notes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input): "_May include a delete icon in supporting browsers_".

Comment: See also [Override the -webkit-search-cancel-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928819/override-the-webkit-search-cancel-button) and [Clear icon inside input text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258521/clear-icon-inside-input-text) for some possible solutions for altering the appearance of the `x`.